# Probability mapping from lower to higher dimension with noise

Tags: probability, integration, density-function, substitution

I'm aware that for a function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $m < n$ and a random vector $z$ with probability $p(z)$ than $y = f(z)$ has a distribution of zero measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by [Sard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem). Note that although I'm aware of it that theorem is way above my knowledge to comprehend its proof. However, I'm interested in using something similar to the change of variable formula to find the density of $\hat{y} = y + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. In this case, though the Jacobian is rectangular if we consider the combined vector $(x, \epsilon)$, so I'm not sure how to proceed there? A simple example would be $f(x) = Wx$.

Comment: This plays an important role in the newly-proposed WGAN, I think. It seems that a satisfactory expression has not yet been found.

Comment: You could use the *delta method*, pretending that $f$ is affine and the size of $\epsilon$ is tiny, writing the approximate distribution of $\hat y$ as a gaussian convolved with the push-forward of $p$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson thanks, but they seem to relate the result in a slightly different angle towards changing their f-divergence.

Comment: @kimchilover that is true, but the main issue is how to calculate $p$ on its own in the ambient space as the Jacobian is rectangular and the distribution itself has zero measure.

Comment: So work out the covariance of $\hat y =Wx+\epsilon$, which will be the sum of a singular covariance matrix and a nonsingular one.  If $x$ is $m$-dimensional gaussian then $\hat y$ will be $n$-dimensional gaussian, and its density calculable.  This is what I had in mind, at any rate.  Remind me what $p$ is?  The density of $z$, or of $y$, or of $\hat y$.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes that is one way, but I was avoiding it. Basically assume that $p(z) = \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and then you have like a FF network - that is $f$ is a composition of functions $f_i = h(W f_{i-1} + b_{i-1})$ where the dimensionality of the functions progressively increases from $m$ to $n$. If they were the same than the log det of the Jacobian can be calculated.